# form.submit() takes too long

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP application that submits a form. The problem is that when I try to submit the form (it’s quite a big form with a lot of values), it takes about 25 seconds to submit it.

Any idea what are some best practices to improve the time for submission or why is it taking too long to submit?

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: There's no way we can know why it takes so long if we can't see any of the code. The total time for a form submission is split between uploading the data and how your server processes that data. Unless you're uploading multiple megabytes of data, then it isn't the network. It's your server processing that data.

Comment: Do the 25 seconds include uploading of files? Does it include the response from the API? Does it include a lot of validation or something?

Comment: @MikeC Sorry but I can't post the code. It has a lot of inputs on it.

Comment: @Sebastian Then no one can help you. Either you're uploading a *whole lot* of data, which means you're restricted by your network, or your server is taking too long to process it. Without knowing *how* you're processing it, we can't give you any advice.

Comment: @randy It does not include uploading files or response from the API. It includes only one validation on a single field. The main problem is that this submit takes 25 seconds on one environment (Test environment with one server) and on another it takes around one and a half minute (INT environment with two servers that are doing some balancing)

Comment: @Sebastian They were asking if that 25 seconds was the combined time of uploading the data, performing validation, and getting a response from the server. You at least need to give us a ballpark of how much data you're submitting.

Comment: @MikeC no, those 25 seconds were just submitting the form, any other action happens after those 25 seconds.

Comment: Taking more than a second is an *extremely* long time if you're talking about a service that faces the public web. 25 seconds is horrendous, and 1.5 minutes is worse. Try replacing the server implementation of that function with an empty function that returns success and see if things get faster. Then try sending less data. Etc. Basically, you're going to need to debug this using a "binary search" implemented in meat-space...

Comment: @Sebastian So you're saying that after 25 seconds your server begins to work on your data then some amount of time after that it sends back a response? If that's the case then you're limited by your network. Maybe consider sending the data in chunks or something. You can't magically speed up file transfer time.

Comment: @MikeC the code belongs to the company and I can't post it, but I can tell you that the form contains around 150 inputs on it. The main thing that bothers me is that this submit takes a lot less on a single server than it does on two servers

Comment: @MikeC yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Sebastian You don't have to post your *exact* company code. Just something that illustrates the point. These two servers: are they on different networks? Do they have different processing power? If it's the same network but one isn't as powerful then you're measuring this wrong and it's your server code that's too slow. 150 inputs is a lot but if they're text or something then it's not *that* much data. However, if this is like 150 files and the servers are on different networks, then your network is to blame.

Comment: @MikeC the servers are identical and on the same network and also the inputs are only check boxes, texts and radio buttons.

Comment: @Sebastian Then your server code is too slow. That's all there is to it. You need to perform some profiling and optimize your code. Make sure you're not iterating over the dataset any more than you absolutely have to and if you're inserting it into a database, reduce the number of transactions required to make that happen.

Comment: @MikeC I perfectly agree with you but I can't do that right now. It would be acceptable if it will take about 30 seconds to submit it but why when I am on the INT environment it takes 3 times longer than on test to do that, even though it should be a lot faster ? That is what bothers me the most.

Comment: @Sebastian Again, it's impossible to say. Assuming you're using the same code on the same hardware on the same network sending the same amount of data with the same number of bounces then it would be impossible for their to be a difference between the two. One or more of your assumptions would have to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn’t provide code examples or other specific information, you’ve got plenty of options, like refactoring the server and client scripts:

**Client**: Instead of classically submitting the form, you could use JavaScript to serialize your form data and send it in a responsive fashion, so your user notices the transmission and patiently waits for it to complete. That way, you could show an activity indicator or set a timeout. Also, you can filter data that doesn’t have to be submitted (`submit()` doesn’t do that). You could also split the data to be uploaded into some requests, to reduce time of each request.

**Server**: This doesn’t look like an ASP-specific issue, while your server-side might be the bottleneck. If your server script has complex processing routines or has to do time-consuming operations, you might consider start optimizing, like by merely saving data on request and schedule server-side processing. Concerning servers, there even might be a problem in your network topology, in which case it can’t be helped by programmers alone.

Again, you didn’t provide enough information to be specific. For form submitting, 25 seconds is an eternity. What kind of data do you transfer (text-only, binary)? What exactly is “a big form with a lot of values”? Can’t you share part of your client and server code respectively? Have you measured time (resolving, submitting, processing, etc.)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that the problem is indeed from the vbScript part. We want to encode everything that is submitted to the server and we work with a COM object that makes a wrapper to the Request. the thing this that this Request is a non editable collection and in order to do some decoding we have to create another dictionary and this is taking on INT about 40 seconds. We have to find a solution for this, but your answer was the one that lead to this. Thank you